# Can I get root access on my Nexus 4 without installing custom bootloader, recovery or ROM?

Tags: rooting, nexus-4

I own a Nexus 4 device and I want to just get root access on my phone so that I can install applications such as AdBlock etc.

I was able to find tutorials online guiding how to root the Nexus phone. But in all those they flash a custom recovery and have to install a custom ROM.

I don't want to install any custom recovery or ROM.

Is it possible to just root my phone without doing those?

Comment: I just added your question (device) to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575). You can browse there for possible methods until somebody posts a solution here. With some luck, one of the available methods listed there proves helpful. Good luck meanwhile!

Answer (score 5):

The [Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) is the way to go, tho note that to unlock the bootloader, you will have to wipe your device.  However, you'll only have to do this once, so when Google's next update removes your root priveleges, you can just run the Root utility in the toolkit.  If the toolkit can't reboot your Nexus 4 into the bootloader, you can do it manually with [adb](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html):

```
adb reboot-bootloader
```

in cmd and then run the toolkit's Root. If it just reboots normally, try again and it should eventually boot into a recovery tool.  Choose the reboot into system option and it will prompt to fix the su binary permissions and you'll be rooted again.

Comment: Although I can't understand the point of why you would want to do what the OP is asking for as you can get everything back to normal essentially by re-locking the bootloader, I guess this is how you would do it, so +1

Answer (score -1):

XDA will be your friend here. BUT here is a tool kit that will root without flashing recovery as long as you dont check the box. MAKE SURE TO BACKUP YOUR STUFF!!!

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2015469

Basically it involves downloading the *Nexus root kit* from http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/, which will not only lead you through the rooting process, but includes a lot of maintenance tools. A video demo can be found [at youtube](http://youtu.be/DIL1iTr5vto). Screenshots are included with the thread.

I personally suggest to flash recovery and unlock the bootloader but it is your decision.

Good luck!