# Nexus 4 rooting troubles

Tags: rooting, nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean

- Installed `superSu` via Clockword Mod from [here.](http://download.chainfire.eu/350/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.60.zip)
- `/system/xbin/su` **exists**
- SuperSu Error / Output of Root Checker:

[image: SuperSu Error] [image: Output of Root Checker]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

What next steps would you guys recommend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get root access on my Nexus 4 without installing custom bootloader, recovery or ROM?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43906/can-i-get-root-access-on-my-nexus-4-without-installing-custom-bootloader-recove)

Comment: That question is NOTHING alike, no offence, but did you read my question?

Comment: No offense, but did you search google for the rooting procedure in the first place? It's a nexus and it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Considering my question references clockwork mod, superSu, and the su executable (and it's path), you can conclude that I have a reasonable understanding of rooting.